# PATH variable not updating when sourcing .bashrc inside vim

Tags: bash, vim

Sourcing .bashrc file inside vim doesn't update PATH variable.

This is the scenario:

- I have two terminals open.
- I exported a new PATH to .bashrc on one terminal using the command `echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/home/xyz/abc/polyglot/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`and then close the terminal.
- I then run `:! source ~/.bashrc` from the vim instance of the other terminal. It sources without complaining.
- I then type in `! echo $PATH` from within vim. The PATH variable doesn't reflect the updated change.

If I open a new terminal and `echo $PATH` , it displays the updated value which is as expected. But no matter how many times I source .bashrc within vim , the variable doesn't get updated. Could someone explain this behavior?

Comment: I don't believe `!` commands use the same bash session. I think the PATH commands should be in `~/.bash_profile` since that should be loaded in a non interactive session. You might need play around with the flags in `shellcmdflag`.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980 http://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you execute a shell command from inside `vim` with `:!`, `vim` creates a new subshell environment. When the command finishes, the subshell terminates and all of its environment disappears.

So it doesn't matter how times you create a new shell and set `PATH` inside that shell; it's only the one used to execute the `echo` which counts, and in that one, you haven't sourced your profile.

The easiest solution is to source your profile *before* you start up `vim`, so that the subshells `vim` creates will inherit `$PATH`.

By the way, `.bashrc` is generally only used for *interactive* bash shells, and the shells created by `vim` are not interactive. `vim` uses `bash -c` to invoke the shell and pass it a string to execute, although the precise invocation is controlled by the `shell` and `shellcmdflag` variables. In particular, if you tell `vim` to create login shells, by adding `-l` to the options in `shellcmdflag`, then the bash shell will automatically source `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile` if `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist); that's generally a more useful place to put environment settings.

Answer (score 5):

Everything stated by rici is correct as to the source of your problem. However, the solution is actually simple: if you can't set your PATH before invoking Vim, Vim lets you edit the current environment directly.

```
:let $PATH=$PATH.":/home/xyz/abc/polyglot/bin"
```

So if you need a new path, write it to a Vimscript file and source from there, instead of sourcing `.bashrc`.